# pivot datatable in c# with many values and conditional

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, lambda, extension-methods

I've a DataTabel in **C#** with data like

`pr     inv    comm  comm1   comm2
 123    1       10    0        1
 234    1       20    5        10
 345    1       40    16       21
 098    2       23    65       76
 765    2       45    32       0
 981    1       65    87       9
 981    2       45    32       100`

I want the result as

`pr    comm    comm1   comm2     comm    comm1    comm2
         1       1     1         2        2        2 
 123     10      0      1        0        0        0
 234     20      5      10       0        0        0
 345     40      16     21       0        0        0
 098     0        0     0        23       65       76
 765     0        0     0        45       32       0 
 981     65      87     9        45       32       100`

what I mean is I've to generate new columns for each and every `inv` column values using. columns comm, comm1,comm2,etc are dynamic. without for loop required.

I asked the same question in sql server but the issue that come up was limited number of columns.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Create the new data table then group the original DT by 'inv' then do a foreach on the IGrouping result and fill the new DT with the result